# Android Studio и libgdx

Tags: android-studio, libgdx

Я хочу использовать ресурсы из папки values конкретно string.html  в проекте на libgdx

```
TextButton startButton = new TextButton("Start", textButtonStyle);
```

возможно ли вместо текста "Start" вызвать нужный ресурс из string.html?

Answer (score 1):

Нашел для себя выход, все классы из папки core.java.ваш.проект переносим в android.java.ваш.проект
При этом теряется возможность decktop но если вы пишете игру исключительно под андроид то это отличный вариант совмещения  Android Studio и libgdx